# User Profile Synchronization Service missing

Tags: user-profile-service

I am using Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise with an administration user.
The option "User Profile Synchronization Service" is missing 
in Central Admin/Manage Service Applications

Do you know why? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you created the service application?

Comment: Do you mean the User Profile Service Application ? Yes that is started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User Profile Synchronization Service is not listed in Central Admin/Manage Service Applications.

Instead you find it under Central Admin / System Settings / Manage services on server.

Beware that you need to run Internet Explorer as administrator, or use the Central Administration launcher on the server, to be able to see this menu option

Comment: Before asking you can also search on google for where the actual location for service.

Comment: +1 for stating the administrative part. you have to run as admin else some options may be missing as it's most unwanted thing for microsoft windows.

Comment: Is it tied to a specific version of SP2013? I don't see it in the "Services on Server" page and I'm a local admin and farm admin, running IE as an administrator. Don't see it via the Central Admin launcher either. The last entry I see is "SharePoint Server Search".

Answer (score 0):

If missing on "Services on Server" - run in powershell:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Install-SPService
```